# Plotting a sum does not display anything

Tags: plotting

I have run into a problem with plotting a sum.

The background is calculating the occupation number of bosons in a one dimensional box.

Bosons follow the Bose-Einstein statistics:

$\qquad f_{BE}(E_i)=\frac{g_i}{\exp\left(\frac{E_i-\mu}{k_B T}\right)-1}$

with the energy $E_i$ of the state $i$, its degeneracy $g_i$, the chemical potential $\mu$, Boltzmann´s constant $k_B$ and the temperature $T$.

For the one dimensional case we have $g_i=1$ and $E_i=ni^2$ (where I set the level spacing equal to 1). $ni$ is a natural number running from $0$ to $nmax$.

I also want to scale some variables; i.e., I set $\frac{\mu}{k_B T}\rightarrow mu$ and $k_B T\rightarrow t$

```
fBE[ni_, mu_, t_] := 1/(Exp[ni^2/t - mu] - 1)
nmax = 100;
n[mu_, t_] := Sum[fBE[ni, mu, t], {ni, 0, nmax}];
Plot[n[mu, 10], {mu, -10., -0.001}]
```

For bosons the (scaled) chemical potential has to be negative because of physical reasons.
Sometimes things diverge for $\mu\rightarrow 0$ therfore I just plot from $[-10,-0.001]$.
The plot however results in an empty plot for values of $t$ smaller than 15.

But when I make a list with `{mu, n[mu, t]}` (for a given t) and use `ListPlot` I get a plot.

```
nList = Table[{mu, n[mu, 10]}, {mu, -10, -0.001, 0.01}];
ListPlot[nList]
```

So why can´t I just use plot? Am I missing something?

Comment: Put a semicolon after the definition of fBE and it plots OK.

Comment: Would you edit your post to add a bit at the end, This <code> doesn't Plot and this <slightly changed code> does Plot so that the reader can scrape-n-paste each and see exactly what you are seeing?

Comment: I can duplicate your problem on my system. See the answer I posted below.

Comment: @bill s : This somehow doesn´t work for me.

Comment: Using exactly the code in grey that you have above, in V10.1 if I evaluate your first three lines of code and then evaluate in either order the Plot or the the two lines for ListPlot I see a well formed graph for each of them, but the ListPlot has a few more scruffy dots.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me to be a bug in `Plot` when `nmax` gets large. On my system (V11.0.1 running on OS X 10.10.2) "large" means `nmax = 85`. I suspect `Plot` is getting into some numerics difficulty.

It is easy to demonstrate the problem by making `nmax` an argument to `n`.

```
fBE[ni_, mu_, t_] := 1/(Exp[ni^2/t - mu] - 1)
n[mu_, t_, nmax_] := Sum[fBE[ni, mu, t], {ni, 0, nmax}]

Plot[n[mu, 10., 84], {mu, -2, -1}]
```

[image: plot84]

```
Plot[n[mu, 10., 85], {mu, -2, -1}]
```

[image: plot85]

Note: You really don't need to sum to anything like 100 to make a plot. I made one with `nmax = 20` and got a quite decent plot.

```
 Plot[n[mu, 10., 20], {mu, -10, -.1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot20]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I´m glad that someone else also experiences this problem.
Unfortunately in the future I would like to perform quantitative calculations with reasonable values where $N_{max}$ is much bigger than 80.
But I guess I then have to use the ListPlot version for visualization.